# Create table in excel with DataTable and Interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm creating excel from datatable using Interop Library so my method is simple as:

```
 public bool WriteDataTableToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable, string worksheetName, string saveAsLocation, string ReporType)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCellrange;

            try
            {
                // Start Excel and get Application object.
                excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                // for making Excel visible
                excel.Visible = false;
                excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

                // Creation a new Workbook
                excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                // Workk sheet
                excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
                excelSheet.Name = worksheetName;


                excelSheet.Cells[1, 1] = ReporType;
                excelSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

                // loop through each row and add values to our sheet
                int rowcount = 2;

                foreach (DataRow datarow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    rowcount += 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // on the first iteration we add the column headers
                        if (rowcount == 3)
                        {
                            excelSheet.Cells[2, i] = dataTable.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                            excelSheet.Cells.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                        }

                        excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();

                        //for alternate rows
                        if (rowcount > 3)
                        {
                            if (i == dataTable.Columns.Count)
                            {
                                if (rowcount % 2 == 0)
                                {
                                    excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, 1], excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                                    FormattingExcelCells(excelCellrange, "#CCCCFF", System.Drawing.Color.Black, false);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                // now we resize the columns
                excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                excelCellrange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders border = excelCellrange.Borders;
                border.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                border.Weight = 2d;


                excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[2, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                FormattingExcelCells(excelCellrange, "#000099", System.Drawing.Color.White, true);


                //now save the workbook and exit Excel


                excelworkBook.SaveAs(saveAsLocation); ;
                excelworkBook.Close();
                excel.Quit();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                excelSheet = null;
                excelCellrange = null;
                excelworkBook = null;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// FUNCTION FOR FORMATTING EXCEL CELLS
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="range"></param>
        /// <param name="HTMLcolorCode"></param>
        /// <param name="fontColor"></param>
        /// <param name="IsFontbool"></param>
        public void FormattingExcelCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range, string HTMLcolorCode, System.Drawing.Color fontColor, bool IsFontbool)
        {
            range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(HTMLcolorCode);
            range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(fontColor);
            if (IsFontbool == true)
            {
                range.Font.Bold = IsFontbool;
            }
        }
```

It's working perfect. But now I want to create a table of my content, because every time excel is open I need to go to Insert tab, select headers and content of my table then clic on "Table" as:

[image]

Is it possible to create table? As you can see in `WriteDataTableToExcel` method I have a `foreach` where I fill excel with data of DataTable, so I want to do a table with that data.

How can I achieve that?

Note: I don't know how many rows I have in datatable, so I don't know what is the Column and rows range, that's why I need to create table depending of Datatable

Comment: last part is unclear ! You already have created the table in excel with your own data? Why do you want another table?

Comment: I want to format it as a table @PrathapG

Comment: you already created a table from your code, isn't it?